# System persisting logic operates differently on same steps

Tags: acumatica

I have two environments. 1 online, the other is local.

*Online is Production environment: win server 2016, sql server 2016, IIS 10.0, .net frameword 4.7.1, Acumatica 19.100.0122

*Local is development environment: windows 10, sql server 2016, IIS 10.0, .net frameword 4.7.2. Acumatica 19.100.0122

The two environments operate differently when I did the same steps as below:
1,Create a new item named "TESTTODEL"
2,Without any transaction on this new item "TESTTODEL", delete it immediately after creation.

Tip: Per Acuamtica's logic, the "TESTTODEL" won't be physically deleted in the Database. It will be  just marked as "DeletedDatabaseRecord=1" in DB table InventoryItem.

Here comes the different
3. Try to recreate a new item also named "TESTTODEL"
In local, it saves successfully, the "DeletedDatabaseRecord" changes to 0 in DB, and all the other information updates as new input. So, acutally,**it is a "Update" operation.**

However, in Online, it won't allow to save, says "Can not insert duplicated line into object "dbo.InventoryItem" with unique index. The duplicated key is (5,TESTTODEL)"
Obviously, **it is an "Insert" operation at this time.**

So why is the different? Could anybody help me find out?

Comment: Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), specifically the bottom section, before editing tags into your title again. It clearly states: _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Comment: Do you have any customizations which refer to InventoryID as a foreign key?

Comment: Also, compare the settings of the Segmented Keys and Numbering Sequences.

Comment: Hello Samvel, as I checked, there is no customizaions refer to InventoryID as a foreign key. Acutally, both online and local are with same customization package. And the segmented keys and numbering sequences setting are exactly the same. Could you reproduce my steps in your environment, what is it like?